# this no callback for scrapy request

Tags: python, scrapy

I add a download middleware for my project. If I don't not add the `sleep` function in `process_request`, it works fine, but if i add it, there is no callback for my request.

```py
class picMiddleware2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if request.url != "https://www.aqistudy.cn/historydata/":
            time.sleep(1) # if i delete this code, it works fine
            return scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url=request.url, body="ddddd", encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

The below is my setting config for the middleware:

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'air_history.middlewares.picMiddleware2': 545,
   # 'air_history.middlewares.AreaSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

I just want to know why it performs like this.

Comment: Does it only fail when you also enable your middleware? Otherwise, please modify your question to provide the simplest code that can reproduce the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve